# MySQL - Getting Top n records and ordering by a specific column with pagination

Tags: mysql, pagination, limit

I have got a problem with getting top n records from database and ordering them by a specific column and paginating them.

For example I want first 100 movies from movie table and order these first 100 records by name and display 10 records per page.

However this doesn't work;

```
SELECT name FROM movies ORDER BY id DESC, name DESC, LIMIT 0,10
```

I am quite confused here. In order to paginate I have to use LIMIT in such ways;

```
LIMIT 0,10 = FIRST PAGE
LIMIT 10,20 = SECOND PAGE
```

and so on.

In order to get first records, I use `ORDER BY id DESC` however when I want to list FROM Z to A, `ORDER BY id DESC, name DESC` doesn't do the trick.

In another words what I want to do is to get first (latest) 100 records out of 10.000 and order this 100 records by name (ASC or DESC) and / or by view (ASC or DESC).

I hope I was clear enough to explain my problem.

I will be glad if you could help me out with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift the order of your `order by` statements
(updated)

```
select   name 
from     ( select    * 
           from     movies 
           order by id desc 
           limit 100 ) 
order by name desc 
limit    0,10
```

It uses the first one first and if equal it looks at the next one

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. Instead of latest (first 100) records this will get Z-A first 10.

What I want to do is to get latest 100 records out of 1000 and order them by Z-A or A-Z as or view number ASC or view number DESC.

Comment: Yep definately, I was also working on building such query now :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your select in another select;

```
SELECT name FROM (SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,100) ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Edit: Updated limits.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use 
select name from 
(select name from movies order by id desc limit 0,100)
order by name desc limit 0,10